# Use of undeclared type AppDelegate

Tags: swift, xcode

I need to do access methods in my AppDelegate from a ViewController (I know it's not ideal but such are my needs right now).

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

Gives me an error

> Use of undeclared identifier AppDelegate

I'm suspecting this might have something to do with the fact that the project is divided into multiple subprojects in a workspace. The same line works fine in a simple single view project.

Comment: The file containing `AppDelegate` and the view controller must share the same target membership.